# Image container with fixed size

Tags: html, css

I have the following image container :

```
<div class="images">
    <img src="<%=imageURL %>" />
</div>
```

And the css for `.images` is :

```
.images{
display:inline-block;
width:100px;
height:133px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

My images are of different dimensions thats why I am using the above div capsule to make them same sized. But in the page, my images are coming like this :

[image]

Their tops are not aligned. How can I rectify that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `vertical-align:top`

```
.images{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    height:133px;
    overflow:hidden;
    vertical-align:top
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use float

```
.images{
       float:left;
       width:100px;
       height:133px;
       overflow:hidden;
      }
```